# Iterate through a Hashmap and store values in variables for use

Tags: android, mysql, hashmap

Hello I retrieved some data from a MySQL database and I stored this data in a Hashmap. I also have created a class which has the same variables as the Hashmap. I want to iterate through the Hashmap and store the values so I can use them for each object. Any ideas how to do it?

```
 public void updateJSONdata() {

cafebartablesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();  

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

try {

    cafebartables = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);


    for (int i = 0; i < cafebartables.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c =cafebartables.getJSONObject(i);

        int tableId = c.getInt(TAG_TABLE_ID);
        int tableMarginLeft = c.getInt(TAG_MARGIN_LEFT);
        int tableMarginTop = c.getInt(TAG_MARGIN_TOP);
        int isFree = c.getInt(TAG_ISFREE);

        map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        map.put(TAG_TABLE_ID, tableId);
        map.put(TAG_MARGIN_LEFT, tableMarginLeft);
        map.put(TAG_MARGIN_TOP, tableMarginTop);
        map.put(TAG_ISFREE, isFree);

        cafebartablesList.add(map);


    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public  void printMap() {
LoadMap ld = new LoadMap();

ld.execute();

}

public class LoadMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    updateJSONdata();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

}
}
}
```

Comment: According to your code you only storing single (Last one)data because you are using single key in hashmap.

Comment: Any recomendations how to make it work @Anjall Tripathi?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you want to do that? You're making your life difficult. There's a LinkedHashMap behind every JSONObject, so just use the JSONObject as is, without any conversion. I.e., use `ArrayList<JSONObject>` instead.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Instead your answer was very helpfull! Thank you very much!!